# begin android developing tips

Tags: java, android

I'm a new programmer and I would like to start learning programming for android . 
I tried to learn from the android developer but it seems hard to me so any tip about where should I start ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should almost certainly start learning java first before you jump into android.

Java is basic on Android - it is unavoidable. Starting right with android is a bit like jumping into the deep end at the pool before you've actually learned to swim.

I would recommend codingbat.com - a lot of high school teachers use it in their classes because it is fairly straight forward, you can run everything in the browser, and the problems are pretty good. There are great tutorials on youtube, but you may find that you like reading better. Check out the oracle docs  are a great resource for learning, as well. You can find them here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/'

Once you do get through at least some java (I recommend going all the way up to and through the AP Problems on codingbat), take a look at Derek Bana's youtube channel. I've found that he posts great turoails on xml, sql, json, and android development - all the stuff you'll need to make some great apps.

Best of luck!

Comment: ok but after learning java should I learn c++ ?

Comment: Why c++? I do all of my programming in java.